# How convert to linq request?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-4.1

```
var list = new List<ListCreaditInBankView>();
var banktemp = m_banksRepository.Banks;
foreach (Bank bank in banktemp)
{
    var bankbranchtemp = m_banksRepository.BankBranches.Where(x => x.BankId == bank.Id);
    foreach (BankBranch bankBranch in bankbranchtemp)
    {
        var creditortemp = m_creditorsRepository.Creditors.Where(x => x.BankBranchId == bankBranch.Id);
        list.Add(new ListCreaditInBankView(){Bank = bank, Creditors = creditortemp});

    }

}
```

I need get `List<ListCreaditInBankView>` without these cycles.

I tried, but it only gets a `Creditors`

```
var lists = (from bank in banksTemp
                         let creditorBank = m_creditorsRepository.GetCreditorBank(bank.BankBranches.Select(x => x.Id).ToList())
                         select new ListCreaditInBankView() {Bank = bank, Creditors = creditorBank}).ToList();
```

Comment: Entity framework or Linq2SQL?

Comment: @mattytommo how can you tell from this code? :) I can write you an identical code with Linq2EF.

Comment: @walther I have jedi powers :). Nah it's just a guess really :)

Comment: @walther looks like my jedi powers are terrible, it's Entity Framework :)

Comment: @mattytommo, and how did you find that out? Chat? Can't see his reply here...

Comment: @walther the tags have since been updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var lists = (from bank in m_banksRepository.Banks
             select new ListCreaditInBankView
             {
                 Bank = bank,
                 Creditors = creditorsRepository.GetCreditorBank(bank.BankBranches
                     .Select(x => x.Id).ToList())
             }).ToList();
```

Or if you prefer the other style LINQ (`method chaining` it's called, thanks Numan :)):

```
var lists = m_banksRepository.Banks
             .Select(bank => new ListCreaditInBankView
             {
                 Bank = bank,
                 Creditors = creditorsRepository.GetCreditorBank(bank.BankBranches
                     .Select(x => x.Id).ToList())
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: The other style is called as method chaining! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linq 2 Entity framework, there's another approach you can try.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx

You just need to be sure, that you've set your tables and keys in your database correctly (or at least mapping in the generated model), otherwise it won't work.